# Xamarin forms - Multiple header on listview

Tags: c#, android, ios, listview, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin form(PCL) having two projects:Android and IOS

I want listview with multiple header but I don't want to use third party for eg:

```
Super group 1
   _Group 1
     _item 1_1_0
     _item 1_1_1
   _Group 2
     _item 1_2_0
     _item 1_2_1
Super group 2
  _Group 1
     _item 1_1_0
     _item 1_1_1
  _Group 2
     _item 1_2_0
     _item 1_2_1
```

Please help to achieve multiple header in listview

Answer (score 0):

You need nested grouped listview. You will need to define your grouped listview containing grouped listview. To define your list view as grouped define list view in xaml as

```
<ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding yourItemList}" 
            IsGroupingEnabled="True"
            GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
            HasUnevenRows="True">
```

Check [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85874/enhancing-xamarin-forms-listview-with-grouping-headers-bind-itemtemplate-to-whole-list) forum of xamarin for more info. You can go through example by James Montemagno [here](http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarinforms-listview-with-grouping). Hope it helps.

Comment: In given example,only one level grouping shown. I want multiple level grouping

Comment: yepp I know its one level grouping. I can only suggest to nested grouped listview. You need to do some r&d for that. You can start and if have any complications you can use SO.

Comment: Thanks for it. I have already implemented one level grouping. But after so my tried not getting success in multiple grouping.

Comment: Do you know in advance how many levels you need? is it always 2?how about creating custom listview cell which includes 2 header and another listview?